# Python plot label

Tags: python, matplotlib, label

I have to plot around 10 different mass profiles. At the moment I am manually entering the mass in the label column of pyplot.

```
plt.plot(np.log(dist_2[1:]/var2['r200'][:20]), np.log(sigma_num_2),'b-o', color = 'b', label = "MASS1 = 7.6x10^13")
```

Does label only take manually entered strings or is there a way to specify say `label = mass` so that it takes the value of the variable (in this case mass) as the input?

Comment: is your `mass` a string or can it be converted to a string?

Comment: @zhangxaochen no, it is a numpy array. But all the mass values are the same for a profile.

Comment: can you loop with a certain index to plot the 10 mass profiles?

Comment: @flebool I tried label = mass[:1] but it is not working

Comment: if you're looping, with index `i` for example, you could do something like `label="MASS%d = %.1e"%(i,masses[i])`, where masses[i] is the `i`-th mass, and `i` goes from `0` to `9`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to documentation (http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html):

> label string or anything printable with ‘%s’ conversion.

So in your case to get `label = mass` you have to use `label = "%.1E" % mass` with additional formatting options if needed.

Most probably you have to rethink your `mass` variable. To get what you manually typed in the example additionally to a numeric value you need also a string - equivalent to `MASS1` unless you put the mass values into an array and create plots iterating over this array. In such case you can create `MASSX` labels on the fly based on the array index:

```
indexVal = 0
for massVal in mass: 
    indexVal += 1

    ...code for getting dist_2, var2, sigma_num_2 variables...

    plt.plot(np.log(dist_2[1:]/var2['r200'][:20]), np.log(sigma_num_2),'b-o', color = 'b', label = "MASS%s = %.1E" % (indexVal, massVal))
```

Answer (score 2):

labels have to be strings, format the number [to exponential format using `%e`](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/python25/web/str-format.html#format-codes):

```
plt.plot(..., label = "MASS1 = %.1e" % mass[0])
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the most `matplotlib`ish way of doing it would be to issue a separate `legend()` once the plots were generated.

```
l_plot=[]
for i in range(10):
    x=arange(10)
    y=random.random(10)
    l_plot.append(plt.plot(x, y, '+-'))
plt.xlim(0,12)
plt.legend([item[0] for item in l_plot], map(str, range(10))) #change it to the plot labels say ['Mass = %f'%item for item in range(10)].
plt.savefig('temp.png')
```

[image]